# Does Flutter shared_preferences plugin work on desktop flutter apps?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Flutter desktop apps as in apps running through the flutter framework on windows, mac and Linux. I assume it should not work and I will have to use a database like sembast to store my persistent data on mobile & desktop. Other suggestions also welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desktop solution is go-flutter-desktop 
It support already 
You can check example in 
https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/plugins/tree/master/shared_preferences

Official FDE for shared_preferences, 
please check issue here https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/issues/434

Comment: Thanks might checkout go-flutter-desktop in the future.